# How to get the correct cardinality of a Tensorflow dataset after filtering

Tags: python, tensorflow, dataset

I create a TensorFlow dataset with elements from 0 to 49, then filter it by only keep elements less than 25, as follows

```
import tensorflow as tf
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(50) 
dataset_less_25 = dataset.filter(lambda x: x < 25)
```

However, when I check the cardinality of the new dataset as follows:

```
dataset_less_25.cardinality().numpy()
```

It returns `-2`, which does not make sense. I further checked that the new dataset actually contains 25 elements, so I wonder why `cardinality()` function does not work in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking [the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#cardinality) of this method, there are special integer codes for infinite as well as unknown cardinalities. [Way at the bottom](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data#UNKNOWN_CARDINALITY), wee see that -2 codes for unknown cardinality. That is, the method was not able to infer the dataset size. Actually, `filter` is used as an example for a dataset with unknown cardinality.

Why this is the case, I'm not sure. Digging in the code, the implementation for `cardinality()` is [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.8.0/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py#L2696-L2722). This leads to `gen_dataset_ops.dataset_cardinality`. However I cannot find `gen_dataset_ops` in the codebase. It might be a file that is automatically generated from somewhere else.

I would assume that this method only performs a very rudimentary analysis (e.g. for a `range` Dataset it is very easy to say how many elements there are) without actually evaluating any of the dataset elements, and if this simple method cannot succeed (as it's not clear which elements will pass the filter without actually looking at the elements), it returns "unknown".

Comment: That's exactly right. If you need to track cardinalities of a dataset through transforms that TF cannot easily predict, you'll have to track them in your data structure with your own logic, or, just iterate over the dataset and count them up yourself.